# Lebesgue integral simple function query

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\chi_{(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]}\Big)d\mu = \infty$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Approach:

I swap the sum and the integral (justified by the fact that we have a non-negative function).

Then I am slightly confused.

To evaluate this integral I need to be able to write it as a simple function. In the examples I've seen the function has always been written as a **finite** linear combination of indicator functions.

i.e. $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}b_{n}\chi_{B_{n}}(x)$$ where $B_{n}$ is a measurable set and $b_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\int f d\mu:= \sum_{n=1}^{N} b_{n}\mu(B_{n}).$

Here it seems to be the case that $N=\infty$ and therefore it would be an infinite linear combination. Is this allowed?

Comment: You say you have swapped the integral and sum. Doesn't that mean you get the integral in from of a single simple function? Namely $$\int n\chi_{(\frac 1{n-1}, \frac 1 n]} \, d\mu$$

Comment: @Shashi If i swap them I have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}n\chi_{(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]}.$

But then this a sum of an integral, but I wasn't sure whether I can evaluate this as $n \mu((\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}])$ because the $n$ that is multiplying the measure could be infinite and I thought it had to be a finite linear combination?

Comment: Yes. You can do the integration first, right?

Comment: Notice that  it’s not hard to compute $\int_{-\infty}^\infty n\chi_{(\frac1{n+1}, \frac1n]} d\mu$

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín so is it okay for there to be an infinite number of linear combinations of indicator functions then. My confusion is that the index in the sum goes to $\infty$ and therefore we have an infinite linear combination (potentally). I know that $n \mu((\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]) = \frac{1}{n+1}$ if I can do that.

Comment: You can  switch the integral and the infinite sum by Monotone Convergence Theorem applied to the sequence of partial sums of the series.